# SQL : Comma separated string in one row V/S multiple rows for single column in terms of performance

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, query-performance

I have one table below of signature

```
"tblProperties"

ID int,
DocID int,
PNAME varchar(50),
PVALUE varchar(max),
PType varchar(50),
Users varchar(max)
```

and

indexes

```
create index InxUsers on tblProperties(Users);
create index InxPValue on tblProperties(PVALUE);
create index InxPrDocID on tblProperties(DocID);
```

Here `Users` is the comma separated email address of users.
I am performing different select queries on the table like

```
SELECT DocID
FROM tblProperties 
WHERE PNAME = 'AssignDocument' 
AND PVALUE LIKE '%abc%' 
AND Users LIKE '%ankit@gmail.com%';
```

To achieve to best performance I should split above table in below two tables

```
1) "tblProperties"

ID int,
DocID int,
PNAME varchar(50),
PVALUE varchar(max),
PType varchar(50)


2) "tblUsersDocument"

ID int,
DocID int,
User varchar(320)
```

and indexes

```
create index InxUsers on tblProperties(Users);
create index InxPValue on tblProperties(PVALUE);
create index InxUseEmail on tblUsersDocument(User);
create index InxDocID on tblUsersDocument(DocID);
create index InxPrDocID on tblProperties(DocID);
```

And select query is

```
SELECT p.DocID
FROM tblProperties AS p inner join tblUsersDocument AS u 
on p.DocID = u.DocID 
WHERE p.PNAME = 'AssignDocument' 
AND p.PVALUE LIKE '%abc%' 
AND u.User = 'ankit@gmail.com';
```

Which one is better in terms of performance first one or second one?

I have tested both in `SHOWPLAN_XML` in single batch first one is giving 25% and second one is giving 75% query cost.

Comment: The latter should perform at least a little better, as it doesn't have a preceding wildcard on `u.User`; thus indexing can be used. `p.PValue` has a preceding wildcard on both though, so it makes the query non-SARGable. But, why haven't you tested to see which one performs better? :)

Comment: If you care about performance *don't* stuff multiple values into a field. This violates even the first NF. If you want to *query* that data, it should be a separate 1-N table with an index on the email address.

Comment: BTW "property/value" or EAV tables are a very, very bad design that guarantees slow performance without the flexibility benefits it's supposed to offer. How are you going to store *decimals*? Dates? How are you going to *query* them? There are far better options anyway, like sparse columns, XML or JSON field types. Columnstore indexes can offer huge performance and compression benefits that are negated by EAV tables too